# Optimization and the Hausdorff distance

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, optimization

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and $\delta$ the Hausdorff distance defined on the compact subsets of $X$, recall
$$
\delta(A,B):=\inf\{\varepsilon>0: A\subset \cup_{b\in B}B(b,\varepsilon) , B\subset \cup_{a\in A} B(a,\varepsilon)\}
$$
for each compact $A,B\subset X$, where $B(x,r)$ stands for the closed ball centered at $x$ and radius $r>0$. Now, assume that $f:(X,d)\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and let $K\subset X$ compact, and for each $n\geq 1$ let $K_{n}\subset X$, $K\subset K_{n}$, compact such that $\lim_{n}\delta(K,K_{n})=0$. Define the numbers

$$
f_{0}:=\min\{f(x):x\in K\}, \quad f_{n}:=\min\{f(x):x\in K_{n}\}
$$

It seems "quite intuitive" that, under the above conditions,  $\lim_{n}f_{n}=f_{0}$ but I can not a formal proof of this assertion.

Many thanks in advance for your comments and suggestions.

Comment: If $f^\ast\colon K(X)\to K(\Bbb R)$ is the induced function on the hyperspaces of compact sets, $f^\ast(K)=f[K]$, then the result you want should follow from the fact that $f^\ast$ and $\min\colon K(\Bbb R)\to \Bbb R$ are continuous

Comment: Thanks for your response!